# Why is the value of combobox.Text lagging behind when it's actually changed?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Really weird issue, perhaps someone can shed some light. I have a windows form with a combobox. When you make a selection it's supposed to update another control, so I have

```
Private Sub LoadAssociatedLocations() Handles combobox_categories.SelectionChangeCommitted

        Dim test As String = combobox_categories.Text
```

I've done this in other winforms projects without issue, though for some reason in this case, when the combobox is changed, combobox.Text has the value of the previous selection. The SelectedIndex value is the connect index, but Tex is always the text of the previously selected index. I can just use selected index of course, but I'd like to know what's causing this strange behavior.

Comment: Is databinding involved?  Also, you are missing parameters in your sub.

Comment: Probably the answer lies in the missing code.. 'Does stuff with combobox.text'

Comment: @LarsTech Yes, there's databinding, to a dataview. Though I've used comboboxes this way before without issue. As for the parameters, I usually don't include them with just having Handles and I don't need any data from the parameters.

Comment: @Steve the missing code isn't important. Looking in the debugger at combobox.Text at the start of the code shows the issue I'm talking about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `SelectedItem` property instead.

```
Private Sub LoadAssociatedLocations(ByVal sender As Object, _
                                    ByVal e As EventArgs) _
                            Handles combobox_categories.SelectionChangeCommitted
   TextBox1.Text = combobox_categories.SelectedItem.ToString
End Sub
```

Alternatively, setting the `DropDownStyle = DropDownList` will make the `comboBox1.Text` update properly.

Comment: Doesn't work, I just get a System.Data.DataRow.etc~ string. I have to use DirectCast(combobox_categories.SelectedValue, DataRowView)(0).ToString() to get the string I want. I'd still prefer to know why doing the exact same thing in this form doesn't work, while it works in other forms

Comment: @cost Obviously, you didn't post *what* was in your ComboBox, so yes, you would have to cast it.  If you want to use the `Text` property, you would have to use the `SelectedIndex` event or change the `comboBox1.DropDownStyle = DropDownList`.

Comment: DropDownStyle = DropDownList, that's the difference that made the one form work and this one not. Thank you very much! I like to know about these little things

Comment: How would you take care of this in WPF? There is no DropDownStyle and I don't see an equivalent.

Comment: @cost I'm not familiar enough with WPF to know the equivalent.  WPF is a different beast.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently (at least according to your example) you have two combo boxes. One called `combobox` and one `combobox_categories`. Did you use the wrong one?

Comment: No, that was just a typo when putting this up here. I try to simplify code when I put it on SO